# Codeigniter Call to undefined method error from library class

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am facing some issue with library and controller.

My Library name is - "Destinations_lib"..

in library class there is a method

```
function getfeaturedcity() {

        $cities = $this->featured_cities_list();
        $result = $this->getResultObject($cities);
        return $result;
      }
```

and in controller i am loading like this

```
        $this->load->library('Destinations/Destinations_lib');
        $sCities = $this->Destinations_lib->getfeaturedcity();
        $this->data['featuredcities'] = $sCities['cities'];
```

Now i am getting following error.

```
    An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Destinations_lib::getfeaturedcity()

Filename: /home/www/portal.happyvoyaging.com/application/modules/Home/controllers/Home.php

Line Number: 214

Backtrace:

File: /home/www/portal.happyvoyaging.com/index.php
Line: 155
Function: require_once
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and for anyone that may be struggling with this, one thing worth trying is not using an underscore in the library name.

So if the library created is called `Destinations_lib` try changing it to `Destinations` and update all references in your controller to that.

I don't know *why* this solved my issue but it did.